# Get a custom JSON response from Loopback

Tags: json, node.js, loopbackjs, hateoas, loopback

I made a simple API using Loopback.It works fine and give the result below from this URL.
http://localhost:3000/api/CoffeeShops

```
[
  {
    "name": "Coffee shop 1",
    "city": "City one",
    "id": 1
  }
]
```

I need to change this JSON to this template, By using Loopback middleware.

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "CoffeeShops": [
      {
        "name": "Coffee shop 1",
        "city": "City one",
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:3000/CoffeeShops/1"
          },
          "CoffeeShop": {
            "href": "http://localhost:3000/CoffeeShops/1"
          }
        }
      }
   ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better yet than a middleware, you can use a [remote hook](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Remote-hooks.html)

> Use **afterRemote hooks** to **modify**, log, or otherwise use **the results** of a remote method **before sending it to a remote client**. Because an afterRemote hook runs after the remote method is executed, it can access the result of the remote method, but cannot modify the input arguments.

The following code inside `coffee-shop.js` will do the trick

```
CoffeeShop.afterRemote('find', function(ctx, output, next) {
  ctx.result = {
    _embedded: {
      CoffeeShops: [{
        name: output.name,
        city: output.city,
        _links: {
          self: {
            href: "http://localhost:3000/CoffeeShops/" + id
          },
          CoffeeShop: {
            href: "http://localhost:3000/CoffeeShops/" + id
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  };
  next();
});
```